# How can I get the address of a struct in C?

Tags: c, memory

I'm an absolute newbie to C so this may be a dumb question, warning!

It's inspired by the extra credit section of [Exercise 16](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych17.html) in Learn C the Hard Way, if anyone is wondering about context.

Assuming these imports:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And given a simple struct like this:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

If I create an instance of it on the heap:

```
struct Point *center = malloc(sizeof(Point));
assert(center != NULL);
center->x = 0;
center->y = 0;
```

Then I know I can print the location of the struct in memory like this:

```
printf("Location: %p\n", (void*)center);
```

But what if I create it on the stack?

```
struct Point offCenter = { 1, 1 };
```

Values sitting in the stack still have a location in memory somewhere. So how do I get at that information? Do I need to create a pointer to my new on-the-stack-struct and then use that?

**EDIT:** Whoops, guess that was a bit of an obvious one. Thanks to Daniel and Clifford! For completeness here's the print example using `&`:

```
printf("Location: %p\n", (void*)&center);
```

Comment: Use  the address operator, `&offCenter`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Please post it as an answer :) I mean, really, how Nick is supposed to pick a comment as a best answer?

Comment: Yep, I feel a bit dumb now :) Thanks Daniel. Want to post that as an answer and get it accepted?

Comment: Too late, not worth duplicating.

Comment: Note that `printf`'s `"%p"` format requires a `void*` argument. If you want to print the value of a pointer of some other type, you should explicitly convert it to `void*` : `printf("Location: %p\n", (void*)center);` or `printf("Location: %p\n", (void*)&center);`. It's likely to work without the cast on most systems (since typically all pointers have the same representation), but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I'll remember that (and update the original question)!

Comment: +1 for really investing time/work into a question.

Comment: @Keith:  The point of a `void*` argument in C is that it can accept any pointer type; no cast is required and indeed none should be used - it rather misses the point of a `void*`.

Comment: @Clifford: That's true if the compiler knows the type of the parameter. For a variadic function like `printf`, the prototype doesn't specify the type, and the cast is necessary.

Comment: @Keith: Fair point.  However if casting a pointer caused the address value to change it would rather defeat the point of the %p specifier.

Comment: @Clifford: Casting a pointer to another pointer type *doesn't* change the address it points to. The standard doesn't quite state that explicitly, but it's strongly implied by the description of pointer-to-pointer conversions. For example, if you convert a `foo*` to `bar*`, as long as the result is correctly aligned, converting back to `foo*` is guaranteed to yield a pointer that compares equal to the original.

Comment: @Keith:  I know it doesn't; that was exactly my point. If you want to print the address through %p, casting will have no effect, and if it did, the output would be less than useful in any case.

Comment: @Clifford: If the pointer type has a different representation than `void*` (which is rare but legal), then the cast will have the effect of making it work correctly rather than possibly crashing. `"%p"` requires an argument of type `void*`; passing an argument of any other type causes undefined behavior. (Almost; there's a special-case guarantee that `void*` has the same representation as `char*`, `signed char*`, and `unsigned char*`.)

Comment: @Keith:  OK, conceded. My point is simply is that if the cast is necessary to avoid a crash the output of %p with the cast may not be the actual address at all, rendering it less than useful. While it is important to write code for portability, writing code for portability to hypothetical systems, that either do not exist or upon which the code is never likely to be required to run is perhaps somewhat pedantic.

Comment: @Clifford: The cast avoids undefined behavior. If all pointers have the same representation, it's harmless. If they don't, then the conversion to `void*` will almost certainly result in something meaningful. Given a choice between 100% and 99% portability, why would you choose 99%?

Comment: @Keith: When getting the extra 1% takes 10% longer, renders the code 10% less readable, and allows it to run successfully on 0% additional targets. i.e. on a cost/benefit basis you might not bother. ;-)

Comment: @Clifford: Without the cast, the behavior is undefined. With the cast, the behavior is defined -- and I don't have to care about implementation-specific characteristics.

Comment: @NickKnowlson `printf("Location: %p\n", (void*)&center);` shouldn't this print the location which contains the address of the structure, not the location of the structure in the memory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the "address-of" operator unary `&`.

```
struct Point offCenter = { 1, 1 };
struct Point* offCentreAddress = &offCentre ;
```